# Binding of Angularjs directives with out loading HTML(bootstrap .modal('show'))

Tags: html, angularjs

i have an div which contains angularjs `ng-repeat` directive to list all values. after assigning to `scope` variable which is being used by `ng-repeat` if i load modal using

```
$('#divId').modal('show')
```

all variables are getting loaded, but if i use `document.getElementby('Id')`, i am able to to see variable binding only for

```
{{ }}
```

here is my code

```
<div id="labeltoPrint">
        Date: {{ scpDate }}
  <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in listofItems">
         <td> {{item.name}}  </td>
         <td> {{item.value}} </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

i tried to  `$scope.$apply` but no luck

Thanks
for reading this

Comment: `document.getElementby('Id')` What is `id` means?

Comment: id="labeltoPrint", with document.getElementbyId we can fetch DOM/HTML text

Comment: try `$scope.scpDate` instead of  `ocument.getElementby(....)`

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ i would suggest to to use an angular component for this mixing jquery is pain

Comment: achieved with a ugly workaround with $timeout, now angularjs variables are loading properly :(

Answer (score 0):

After several hits, i did a work around using `$timeOut`, scope variables are getting updated with that, donno why `$scope.$apply` is not updating scope :(

Thanks for reading